# What is the best way to include an external html file into another html file?

Tags: html

When I have one basis html file in which I want to embed a few external html files as sort of a portfolio page, what is the best way to embed those external html files? I now use iframe, but I've read that is not the preferred way? What other options are there and which one is the best?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern websites implement a server-side framework such as php or asp.net that can assemble the final HTML for each page and output it together

The only issue with iFrame is that it causes additional round-trips to the server, as the client has to load each frame individually, but if you don't have access to any server-side scripting then any other solution will do the same thing